# Were there any Dark Lord sympathizers from other countries?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

I can't seem to remember, but were there any followers of Voldemort from other countries, any outsiders that sympathized with Voldemort's aims? (Not Dragomir Despard)
Death Eaters are NOT included in this category.

Comment: Dragomir Despard

Comment: I was. Also the later headmaster of the Bulgarian school.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Giants abroad supported the Dark Lord.

While they’re not wizards, the clearest example of individuals abroad who supported the Dark Lord would be many of the giants and their Gurg, Golgomath.

> “Me an’ Olympe talked it over an’ we agreed, jus’ ’cause the Gurg looked like favourin’ You-Know-Who didn’ mean all of ’em would. We had ter try an’ persuade some o’ the others, the ones who hadn’ wanted Golgomath as Gurg.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 20 (Hagrid’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

The giants lived far from Britain - going from Britain, Hagrid and Madame Maxime had to cross the border of Poland to get to where the giants lived.

> “We chanced a bit o’ magic after that an’ it wasn’ a bad journey. Ran inter a couple o’ mad trolls on the Polish border an’ I had a sligh’ disagreement with a vampire in a pub in Minsk, bu’ apart from tha’ couldn’t’a bin smoother.
>
> ‘An’ then we reached the place, an’ we started trekkin’ up through the mountains, lookin’ fer signs of ’em …
>
> ‘We had ter lay off the magic once we got near ’em. Partly ’cause they don’ like wizards an’ we didn’ want ter put their backs up too soon, an’ partly ’cause Dumbledore had warned us You-Know-Who was bound ter be after the giants an’ all.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 20 (Hagrid’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

It’s clear that at least some giants did indeed support the Dark Lord, as they showed up to fight for him when he went to confront Harry at Hogwarts.

> “His cry was answered by roars from Voldemort’s giants: they ran at Grawp like bull elephants, making the earth quake.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, the Dark Lord had proven supporters abroad among the giants.

## Some foreign wizards likely supported him.

It’s likely that the Dark Lord wouldn’t be as well known in other countries as he was in Britain. However, he was likely known somewhat abroad, since Dumbledore tells everyone from Beauxbatons and Durmstrang about his return without explaining who he is, so he presumably expected they’d already know.

> “Dumbledore looked from Madame Maxime and Hagrid, to Fleur Delacour and her fellow Beauxbatons students, to Viktor Krum and the Durmstrangs at the Slytherin table. Krum, Harry saw, looked wary, almost frightened, as though he expected Dumbledore to say something harsh.
>
> ‘Every guest in this Hall,’ said Dumbledore, and his eyes lingered upon the Durmstrang students, ‘will be welcomed back here, at any time, should they wish to come. I say to you all, once again – in the light of Lord Voldemort’s return, we are only as strong as we are united, as weak as we are divided.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 37 (The Beginning)*</sup></sub>

It’s likely that at least a few of the wizards abroad who knew of him supported his ideas - Grindelwald, another Dark wizard, was able to raise an army, though he avoided Britain because of Dumbledore.

> “But while I busied myself with the training of young wizards, Grindelwald was raising an army. They say he feared me, and perhaps he did, but less, I think, than I feared him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

Since the question asks for those who supported the Dark Lord without actually becoming Death Eaters, it seems very likely that at least some wizards in other countries agreed with his ideas.

## But, his supporters were British in majority.

Though he was likely known at least somewhat abroad, the Dark Lord was mainly based in Britain, so it’s likely that the majority of his supporters were British as well. Sirius Black mentions how his family, along with many others, supported the Dark Lord’s ideals.

> “Were – were your parents Death Eaters as well?’
>
> ‘No, no, but believe me, they thought Voldemort had the right idea, they were all for the purification of the wizarding race, getting rid of Muggle-borns and having pure-bloods in charge. They weren’t alone, either, there were quite a few people, before Voldemort showed his true colours, who thought he had the right idea about things … they got cold feet when they saw what he was prepared to do to get power, though.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

The wizards Sirius refers to were all likely British, since it’s unlikely that he’d know what wizards in other countries thought. Also, it’s logical that the Dark Lord’s supporters would mainly be in Britain, since British wizards would know more about him than foreign ones.

Comment: Was Karkaroff foreign?

Comment: @marcellothearcane It’s not clear, and the question asks about foreign supporters of the Dark Lord who *weren’t* actually Death Eaters, so Karkaroff wouldn’t be included anyway because he was a Death Eater.

Comment: Of course.. I missed the 'not death eater' bit!

Comment: @marcellothearcane That’s fine, thanks for the suggestion! :)